# how to prevent empying an array when switching between pages in Electron?

Tags: javascript, electron

My Electron app creates an empty array when it runs. The array is used to store some information about user that should be shown on the `test.html` page. Since the array is empty by default I add some information about myself to it. Once I provided information about myself it's shown on the `test.html` page (taken form the array). Then I go to another pages and when I come back to the `test.html` my information is not shown because the array is empty again (just like when the app has been just run). How to prevent emptifying the array ?

test.html js part

```js
var information = require('electron').remote.getGlobal('userInfo');
window.onload = function() {
  console.log(information); // just to check if the array has been emptyfied
  if (information.length > 0) { // if I come back to the test page and my information is still stored in the array
    showInformation();
  }
}
```

test.js

```js
var infoRecords = require('electron').remote.getGlobal('userInfo');

function addInformation() {
  infoRecords = []; // if I provide information about myself then I delete the information about the previous user
  ....
  ....
  ....
  ....
  infoRecords.push(name);
  ....
  infoRecords.push(age);
  ....
  showInformation();
}
```

main.js

```js
global.userInfo = []; // it's empty when the app is just run
```